# Ошибка сегментации в программе на С++ с ассемблерной вставкой

Tags: c++, ассемблер

Пишу код на С++ с ассемблерной вставкой. Ищется наибольший и наименьший элемент в массиве. Если компилирую под х64, то получаю:

```
g++ hell.cpp -o hell -no-pie
hell.cpp: Assembler messages:
hell.cpp:54: Error: unsupported instruction `mov'
```

Если компилировать под х32, то получаю ошибку сегментации:

```
g++ -m32 hell.cpp -o hell -no-pie
./hell
Value of 1 element is 7
Value of 2 element is 6
Value of 3 element is 8
Segmentation fault
```

Пробовал посмотреть что там происходит через gdb, но так и не разобрался. Подскажите кто-нибудь, как можно это исправить

Код программы:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
        int arr_size, min, max;
        cin >> arr_size;
        int *arr = new int[arr_size];

        asm (
                "movl %2, %%ecx;"  //указывает на первый элемент массива
                "movl %3, %%ebx;"  //количество итераций для цикла top
                "movl %%ecx, (%0);"//первый элемент массива становится наибольшим
                "movl %%ecx, (%1);"//и наименьшим на данный момент
                "top:"
                        "xorl %%eax, %%eax;"
                        "movl %0, %%eax;"   // %0 будет хранить max элемент
                        "xorl %%edx, %%edx;"
                        "movl (%%ecx), %%edx;"//в edx записывается очередной элемент массива
                        "cmp %%eax, %%edx;"
                        "jge greateri;"

                        "xorl %%eax, %%eax;"
                        "movl %1, %%eax;"   // %1 будет хранить min элемент
                        "cmp %%eax, %%edx;"
                        "jle lessi;"

                        "jmp endi;"
                "greateri:"       //выполняется, если элемент массива больше max
                        "movl %%edx, %%eax;"
                        "movl %%eax, (%0);"
                        "jmp endi;"
                "lessi:"         //выполняется, если элемент массива меньше min
                        "movl %%edx, %%eax;"
                        "movl %%eax, (%1);"
                        "jmp endi;"
                "endi:"
                        "addl $0x4, %%ecx;" //перемещаем указатель на следующий элемент массива
                        "decl %%ebx;"
                        "jnz top;"

                        :"+g"(max), "+g"(min)
                        :"g"(arr), "g"(arr_size)
                        :
                        );

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: С этим ассемблером незнаком, но за такое: `int arr_size, min, max;
        int *arr = new int[arr_size];` детям компич массируют. За сегодня уже *второй раз* выделяют память неопределенного размера! Не слишком ли много для одного дня? :) И еще... Я, конечно, GNUшный ассемблер не знаю, но нигде не вижу строки, например, `Value of` - так что код как минимум явно приведен не весь.

Comment: Не используйте ассемблерные вставки, делайте отдельные полноценные функции и вызывайте их.

Comment: @user7860670 я сначала пробовал именно как вы говорите сделать (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1102894/338360). Ваш совет помог, но там я также получаю ошибку сегментации

Comment: Может быть, но переделка в инлайн вставку тут явно не поможет. Вам надо код править, тщательно проверяя что каждая строчка делает то, что вы думаете, что она делает. А сейчас у вас на весь ассемблер ни одного комментария.

Comment: @user7860670 при вызове тех же самых функций из прошлого вопроса в программе на ассемблере всё прекрасно работало... поэтому и недоумеваю в чем проблема. На счет комментариев согласен, прошу прощения, надо добавлять

Comment: После точки с запятой `;` в ассемблере комментарий до конца строки. Нужно добавлять конец строки `movl %ecx, %ebx;\n`. Чтобы увидеть ассемблерный код используйте `g++ hell.cpp -S -no-pie` Асм код в `hell.s`

Answer (score 0):

В C++ ассемблер пишется так:

```
asm {
push eax
mov eax,0
pop eax
}
```

И спокойно трассируется обычным си отладчиком.